# How to fix string saving as code to word?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, download, save

I have the following code:

```
function downloadNotes() {
  var information = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
  var textToBLOB = new Blob([information], { type: 'text/plain' });
  var sFileName = 'formData = document.doc';

  var newLink = document.createElement("a");

     newLink.download = sFileName;

 if (window.webkitURL != null) {
     newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
 }
 else {
     newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
     newLink.style.display = "none";
     document.body.appendChild(newLink);
 }

     newLink.click();
}
```

When I save my notes, it successfully saves it to word, but when I open it, it shows the code all compressed rather than the string output:
[Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHd7F.png)

Comment: `text/plain` means that HTML isn't parsed, it's just displayed literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```js
var information = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
```

To this:

```js
var information = document.getElementById("text").innerText;
```

Your code was reading the HTML content of the element instead of the Text value of the element. If this doesn't work you may need to code it to cut out the HTML.